# hreflang sitemap with multiple language-region

Tags: html, sitemap, internationalization, hreflang

i have 2 sitemaps only usage for template purpose, and use 2 sub-directory English(also other lang) and China with same contain.

en-sitemap with 15urls (EN sub-directory), the contain like follow:

```
  domain/en/url-1.html
   .. x-default domain/en/url-1.html
   .. en domain/en/url-1.html
   .. es domain/en/url-1.html
   .. (de-de, en-fr, fr, it-it, it and other lang+reg) domain/en/url-1.html
   .. zh domain/cn/url-1.html
   .. en-cn domain/cn/url-1.html
   .. en-hk domain/cn/url-1.html
  domain/en/url-2.html
   .. (same like above till url-15)
```

china-sitemap with 15urls (China Sub-directory), the contain like follow:

```
  domain/cn/url-1.html
   .. x-default domain/en/url-1.html
   .. en domain/en/url-1.html
   .. es domain/en/url-1.html
   .. (de-de, en-fr, fr, it-it, it and other lang+reg) domain/en/url-1.html
   .. zh domain/cn/url-1.html
   .. en-cn domain/cn/url-1.html
   .. en-hk domain/cn/url-1.html
  domain/cn/url-2.html
   .. (same like above till url-15)
```

both sitemap place in root.

the question:

1. is it (valid/correct) to pointing one url for multi language+region? example: en, es, de-de, en-fr point to /en/url-1.html
2. why in google search console-intl targeting hreflang is "zero" but in technicalseo site-hreflang test all is valid?